# how to increase HD in RHEL 5 within VMware

Tags: redhat, fdisk

I have increased the HD from the setting of VMware while the rhel was shut down. I increased it to 20 GB (before it was 5 GB).
But the problem was There is no free allocated space !! please tell me how to increase hdd.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U812x.png

if u see the pic, actually free space should be 21GB but its cylinder endeing in about 1000 not in 2100.

Comment: VMware is a company, not a product. Am I correct in assuming you are using ESXi?

Answer (score 2):

When you increased the hard disk size in ESXi, you were increasing the size of the "physical" disk that is presented to the VM. That's only part of the equation. Now you need to increase the partition size and then increase the filesystem size.

Since you already have GUI installed, just fire up GParted and use that to adjust both partition and filesystem sizes.